# DIMENSION statement in FORTRAN

Tags: c++, fortran

I am converting a FORTRAN code to C++. While understanding the FORTRAN code I came across the following code snippet in FORTRAN.

```
DIMENSION X(50),Y(50),PARA(6,9)                                      
DIMENSION AMPA(12),FCUR(20),VER(20),AMPS(20)
```

I understand that DIMENSION do not need any data type in FORTRAN. But I am not able to understand what will be the default data types for X, Y, PARA etc. Is it integer by default?

Comment: Thank you very much for quick help. Really Appreciate :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Classically, Fortran variables with names starting `[I-N]` were `INTEGER` and everything else was `REAL`.  So, the most likely type for those variables in C++ is `float`.

```
 float X[50], Y[50], PARA[6][9];
 float AMPA[12], FCUR[20], VER[20], AMPS[20];
```

However, with 2D arrays, Fortran uses [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order) where C and C++ use row-major order.  You might need to worry about that for the 2D array.  You might also decide to convert the names to lower-case.

Comment: Is this also same for COMMON statement ?

Comment: Yes, and for function parameters, etc.  That is, the default type based on name follows the same scheme.

Answer (score 2):

In Fortran, variables whose names began with characters from I to N in the alphabet (remembering Fortran is not case sensitive) are [implicitly `integer`, and everything else is implicitly `real`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features#Implicit_and_explicit_typing) unless otherwise stated -- this will probably correspond to `int` and `float` in C++.

Even as far back as FORTRAN 77 this was seen as bad practice, and it's usual today to begin every Fortran program and module with the statement `implicit none` to require every variable to be declared wth an explicit type.